# How to shorten url in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-dynamic-links

Let's say i have a Firebase Storage url that looks like this :

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-id.appspot.com/o/public%2FNyq7dMqe2kcAZGE71YwZ5fsAkV83%2Fphoto_profile?alt=media&token=c78b03fa-b6e4-45a2-90d7-fca917e3c0b4
```

I am looking for an output that would give for example :

```
https://hostname.com/random_id
```

I am aware that `firebase_dynamic_links` allows to shorten urls, is it a correct solution ?

If yes, how can i do that with my example please ?

Comment: "is it the correct solution?" That depends on what "correct" means for you. There's also this example of using only Cloud Functions: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/url-shortener There are probably many more samples out there, so I recommend doing a search for those.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the link. I have correct the grammar to "is it a correct solution" because i would like to use ```dynamic_links``` if possible. I have already checked some other APIs such as the one in your link but the pricing is generally too high for the volume i am planning to make :/

Answer (score 1):

Actually Firebase Dynamic Links would be a nice one solution for your situation.

You can make it runs following these instructions in this [article](https://medium.com/@vejmartin/3-free-ways-to-shorten-urls-with-firebase-c3e023b33083) from Medium, I have just implemented it in one of my Apps and it worked as expected.

I hope it helps you and everyone having the same issue.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i was looking for a way to programmatically do this, not use the Firebase console